# No JSON object could be decoded for the web APIs

Tags: python, json, ipython

I am new to python, and I am currently repeating all the solved examples from the book "python for data analysis"

in one example, I need to access the APIs from twitter search. Here is the code:

```
import requests
url='https://twitter.com/search?q=python%20pandas&src=typd'
resp=requests.get(url)
```

everything works okay up to here. problems comes when I use the `json`

```
import json
data=json.loads(resp.text)
```

then I received the error message `ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded`

I tried to switch to another url instead of the twitter, but I still receive the same error message.

does anyone have some ideas? thanks

Comment: This is because the response isn't JSON, is HTML

Comment: `print(resp.text)` gives what...?

Comment: use api twitter for get json format [for example](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/search/tweets)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a response with JSON content. To search Twitter this requires use of api.twitter.com, but you need to get an OAuth key. It's more complicated than the 5 lines of code you have. See http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/chdoig/Mining-the-Social-Web-2nd-Edition/blob/master/ipynb/Chapter%201%20-%20Mining%20Twitter.ipynb